# Parametrize ZonedDateTime method

Tags: java, design-patterns, modularity

I have a parametrized method:

```
private static Date getTimeFor(int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoSecond, String zoneId) {
    ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.now()
            .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of(zoneId))
            .withHour(hour)
            .withMinute(minute)
            .withSecond(second)
            .withNano(nanoSecond);
    return Date.from(time.toInstant());
}
```

Followed by:

```
    private Date getRomeStartTime(){
        return getTimeFor(8,30,0,0,"Europe/Rome");
    }

    private Date getParisStartTime(){
        return getTimeFor(9,30,0,0,"Europe/Paris");
    }

    private Date getLondonStartTime(){
        return getTimeFor(9,00,0,0,"Europe/London");
    }
```

This can get out of hand quickly as more cities are added. I'm aiming to only make public/expose the below method and delegate the construction of StartTimes elsewhere:

```
public Date getEffectiveTimeFor(String zoneId){
        // Delegate construction as per zoneId elsewhere
        // dont want to use a long-winded if-else statement
    }
```

I cant use the strategy pattern as I should not pass an object, but only a string. 
What is the best approach here?

(p.s. I **have** to return the old `Date`, this is beyond the question )

Comment: Well, you could use a Map<String, LocalTime> to store the start time of each zone ID. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely it! Thank you. My thoughts kept revolving around patterns and functional interfaces as I've spent too much time on them recently. This made me overlook such a simple solution. Feel free to answer, I will accept

Comment: In `ZonedDateTime`, instead of changing each field separately, you can also call `with(LocalTime.of(hour, min, sec, nanosec))`. If you use the map solution suggested by @JBNizet the `with(LocalTime)` call is better as it makes the code clearer and shorter (IMO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `Map<String, LocalTime>` to store the start time for each zone ID. Then get the start time from this map in your method and create the Date from there.